# Using := multiple times in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, colon-equals

I frequently find myself doing a long series of chained calculations using `:=` on the same data table. For example, something like this

```
test = data.table(1:10, 1:10, 1:10, 1:10)

test[, V1 := V1^2]
test[, V2 := V1*V2]
test[, V3 := V2/V3]
test[, V4 := sqrt(V3)]
test[, new := letters[V4]]
```

Having to write `test[, ...]` on every line 1) takes longer to type (not a big issue I can cope with that).  But, more importantly, also distracts visually from the flow and content of the calculation. I would much rather write something like

```
test[, {
  V1 := V1^2
  V2 := V1*V2
  V3 := V2/V3
  V4 := sqrt(V3)
  new := letters[V4]
}]
```

But this throws an error of `You have wrapped := with {} which is ok but then := must be the only thing inside {}`.

I know that I can write

```
within(test, {
  V1 = V1^2
  V2 = V1*V2
  V3 = V2/V3
  V4 = sqrt(V3)
  new = letters[V4]
  })
```

But this loses the efficiency of using `:=`

I tried writing a function to provide this ability

```
with.dt = function(dt, expressions){
  e = strsplit(expressions,'\n')
  for (i in 1:length(e)){    
    dt[, eval(parse(text = e[i]))]
  }
  dt
  }

with.dt(test, "
  V1 := V1^2;
  V2 := V1*V2;
  V3 := V2/V3;
  V4 := sqrt(V3);
  new := letters[V4];
  ")
```

But this does not change the content of the data.table

Is there any syntax that permits the neat look of the `within` version, while retaining the assign by reference property of `:=`?

Comment: If you don't need them done sequentially you can do something like this: `test[,`:=`(v1 = v1^2,
          v2 = v1*v2)]`  There are supposed to be backticks around the `:=`

Comment: Extending what Kristoferson said, I think you can do it sequentially with a hack like `DT[, \`:=\`(V1 = V1 <- 10, V2 = V2 <- V1^2, ...)]`

Comment: @Frank Thanks for the suggestion. I updated the q with another attempt using a function definition for `with.dt`.  Any idea why this does not work?

Comment: Generally, you should make sure your code works before wrapping it in a function. I tried running it and ran into the error "Error in parse(text = e[i]) : <text>:1:1: unexpected '^'". The usual advice for using eval with data.table is to build expressions directly instead of from strings, like `es = expression(V1 := V1^2, V2 := V1*V2); for (e in es) test[, eval(e)]; test`

Comment: it seems to me that you have forgotten `df <- df[, eval ...]` in your `for` loop

Comment: @clemlaflemme One of the features of data.table and `:=` in particular is that the object is modified by reference so you don't need to reassign the result.

Comment: to answer your exact question @dww: No.
However, the answer from @Kristofersen is how to do it.
If you don't intend to keep the original columns you can also use this:
```DT<-data.table(a=1:2,b=3:4);DT[,.(d=5:6,e=7:8,f=a+1)]```

Comment: @Kristofersen it took me forever to realize this but you can escape backticks in comments within an inline code block by backslash: `\\`` will leave it as is: `\`:=\``

Comment: @MichaelChirico Thanks, I was wondering how to do that. Too late to edit that comment, but next time i'll do that.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple different ways to do this.

Original test matrix used here:

```
   v1 v2
1:  1  3
2:  2  4
```

First, we can do something like this:

```
test[,`:=`(v1 = v1^2,
          v2 = v1*v2)
```

Output:

```
v1 v2
 1  3
 4  8
```

Or, if we want it done sequentially we can use Frank's hack.

```
test[, `:=`(v1 = v1 <- v1^2, v2 = v2 * v1)]
```

Output:

```
v1 v2
 1  3
 4 16
```

Or, similarly we could run this:

```
test[,c("v1","v2") := list(v1^2,v1^2*v2)]
```

Output:

```
v1 v2
 1  3
 4 16
```

Comment: or `test[, v1 := v1^2][, v2 := v2*v1]`

Answer (score 1):

We can use a function that takes a list of expressions:

```
with.dt = function(dt, expr){
  for (j in 1:length(expr)) set(dt, , names(expr)[j], dt[, eval(expr[[j]])])
}

test = data.table(1:10, 1:10, 1:10, 1:10)
with.dt(test, expression(
  V1 = V1^2,
  V2 = V1*V2,
  V3 = V2/V3,
  V4 = sqrt(V3),
  new = letters[V4]
))

#     V1   V2  V3 V4 new
# 1:   1    1   1  1   a
# 2:   4    8   4  2   b
# 3:   9   27   9  3   c
# 4:  16   64  16  4   d
# 5:  25  125  25  5   e
# 6:  36  216  36  6   f
# 7:  49  343  49  7   g
# 8:  64  512  64  8   h
# 9:  81  729  81  9   i
#10: 100 1000 100 10   j
```

Comment: Some feedback on the downvote would be more helpful than a simple downvote. What is wrong with this approach? It works, (at least on the example, perhaps there are edge cases if so let me know). Benchmarking it, it is just as fast as a string of separate `:=` calls. So why the downvote? I'll happily remove this answer if someone can tell me a real problem with it, but I'd like to know why.

Comment: downvote is not from me actually, but I can imaging that downvote might be because R language has more to offer than eval-parse. It is good practice to avoid eval-parse if it is possible.

Comment: Yeah, downvoting because, like I said, if you're going to do this, best to at least try to use expressions directly, following advice in FAQ 1.6: https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#ok-but-i-dont-know-the-expressions-in-advance.-how-do-i-programatically-pass-them-in Also, the original question only asks for the vague criterion of looking nice like the `with` version, and I don't think using a string argument can do that (since you'll miss syntax highlighting etc.)

Comment: Dunno, I guess it's fine to leave it.

Comment: @Frank I have it now using expressions and no text or eval(parse).  Better?

Comment: Sure, took back my vote. Fyi, no need to write "updates" in the body of the post. If folks want to see it, they can find the edit history; and if you want to make meta comments, probably better to do it down here. At least that's what I do.