# r data table using `:=` notation, error using a column name created in the interior code

Tags: r, data.table

Here's some code that doesn't work. The idea is to step 1 - update a column, step 2 - add a new column, step 3 - use the new column to update an existing column.

```
library(data.table)
ethanolKcals <- 6.9
ethanol.share.beer <- .04
dt.nutrients <- data.table(carbohydrate_g = runif(10), energy_kcal = runif(10), bevname = c("beer", "wine", "spirits"))
dt.nutrients[bevname == "beer", `:=`(
  carbohydrate_g = carbohydrate_g + 100 * ethanol.share.beer,
  kcals.ethanol_g = ethanolKcals * ethanol.share.beer,
  energy_kcal = energy_kcal + kcals.ethanol_g
)]
```

It appears that data.table doesn't complete step 2 before it starts step 3. I can fix this by moving step 3 to a new statement like

```
dt.nutrients[bevname == "beer",energy_kcal := energy_kcal + kcals.ethanol_g]
```

But was wondering if there is a cleaner solution.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41023553/using-multiple-times-in-data-table

Comment: Following a comment in the link, you could chain these operations. Maybe not much cleaner : `dt.nutrients[bevname == "beer", \`:=\`(carbohydrate_g = carbohydrate_g + 100 * ethanol.share.beer, kcals.ethanol_g = ethanolKcals * ethanol.share.beer)][bevname == "beer", energy_kcal := energy_kcal + kcals.ethanol_g]`.

Comment: I'd say not cleaner at all. One thing I dislike about chaining generally is that you can't put the second [] on a new line; at least I haven't figured out how to do that.

Comment: You can put a new line in straight after a `[` , or you can chain with the `%>%` from `library(magrittr)` : `dt[, newCol := 'hi'] %>% .[, newCol := paste0(newCol, " there")]`

Comment: Your new line comment is a great tip; obvious once it's pointed out :-). Would be nice though, if you didn't have to repeat the i value each time.

Comment: I'm not sure you do need to repeat the i value each time?

Comment: And, I should add, you can put a new line in anywhere inside the `[ ... ]` operation.

Comment: Regarding repeating `i`, I'd instead do `DT[i, (cols) := {yada_yada; .(...)}]` where the `{}` is written over multiple lines. Alternately, just do the `<-` thing in the link (which is a dupe apart from the `i` thing, right?).